# check if value exist in another table before insert SQL

Tags: oracle, trigger, plsql

I have table: " daysoff " and table: " rdv "

**the *rdv* table looks like this :**

| temps_rdv | etat_rdv | ID_RDV |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12-10-2022 | reservee | 2 |

**the *daysoff* table looks like this :**

| ID | DATE_OFF | REASON |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 12-06-2023 | conge |

i want to insert values in rdv table, but before inserting any thing i need to check first if " temps_rdv " doesn't exist in the daysoff table

**example: I can not add a rdv with temps_rdv = 12-06-2023**

I tried a trigger, but it doesn't seem to work

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER1 
    BEFORE INSERT ON rdv
    FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
            IF EXISTS (
                select daysoff.date_off
                From Available daysoff  -- CHANGED THE ALIAS TO A
                where (NEW.temps_rdv = daysoff.date_off)
            ) THEN 
               CALL:='Insert not allowed';
    
            END IF;
    END;
```

I also tried this :

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR2
BEFORE INSERT ON RDV
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE found_it INT;
--     IF (NEW.temps_rdv != "01-01-23" AND NEW.temps_rdv != "02-01-23" AND NEW.temps_rdv != "03-01-23"  ) THEN
        
BEGIN
     SELECT COUNT(1) INTO found_it FROM daysoff
        WHERE NEW.temps_rdv != "01-01-23" AND NEW.temps_rdv != "02-01-23" AND NEW.temps_rdv != "03-01-23";
        IF (found_it = 0) THEN
        INSERT INTO rdv (temps_rdv, etat_rdv, id_rdv, patient_id_p) VALUES (NEW.temps_rdv, NEW.etat_rdv, NEW.id_rdv, NEW.patient_id_p);
        END IF;
    END IF;
END;
```

but none of these worked

Comment: I removed your SQL Server tag as that represents the product Microsoft SQL Server, and it appears you're using Oracle SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_bi_rdv
  2    before insert on rdv
  3    for each row
  4  declare
  5    l_cnt number;
  6  begin
  7    select count(*)
  8      into l_cnt
  9      from daysoff d
 10      where d.id = :new.id_rdv
 11        and d.date_off = :new.temps_rdv;
 12
 13    if l_cnt > 0 then
 14       raise_application_error(-20000, 'Insert not allowed');
 15    end if;
 16  end;
 17  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> insert into rdv (temps_rdv, etat_rdv, id_rdv) values
  2    (date '2023-01-25', 'test', 1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into rdv (temps_rdv, etat_rdv, id_rdv) values
  2    (date '2023-01-25', 'test', 2);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into rdv (temps_rdv, etat_rdv, id_rdv) values
  2    (date '2023-06-12', 'test', 2);
insert into rdv (temps_rdv, etat_rdv, id_rdv) values
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: Insert not allowed
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TRG_BI_RDV", line 11
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.TRG_BI_RDV'


SQL>
```